# AlarmManager not triggered when app manually closed

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I want to make sure AlarmManager is triggered even when my app is manually closed, the same way a messaging app still displayed messages even when closed (swipe or press the "X"). This is my code:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private lateinit var alarmManager: AlarmManager

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
                override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

                    val mp = MediaPlayer.create(context,R.raw.music)
                    mp.start()

                }
            }

            this.registerReceiver(receiver, IntentFilter("SET_ALARM"))

            alarmManager = getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager

            var calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
            calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE,1)
            val alarmIntent = Intent()
            alarmIntent.action = "SET_ALARM"
            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0)

            Column( Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {


                Button(onClick = { alarmManager.setAndAllowWhileIdle(
                    AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    calendar.timeInMillis,
                    pendingIntent)}) {Text("play song in 1 minute")
                }
                
            }
        }
}
```

}

It works fine when the app is open, but not when I close manually it . What do I need to add?

(It is not a battery management problem, as it does not work in the emulator either)

Answer (score 0):

In your AndroidManifest.xml, make sure you have a receiver definition within the  tags, something like:

<receiver android:name="AlarmReceiver"

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am already registering the receiver in the activity so I shouldn't need to define it in the manifest (Official docs: "There are two ways to make a broadcast receiver known to the system: One is declare it in the manifest file with this element. The other is to create the receiver dynamically in code and register it with the Context.registerReceiver() method. For more information about how to dynamically create receivers, see the BroadcastReceiver class description. ")

Answer (score 0):

You said in a comment that you're registering your broadcast receiver through an activity, and not the manifest. That will only receive broadcasts while your app is actually *running* - specifically as long as the `Context` you used to register the receiver is valid. If you used an `Activity` as that context, once that activity is destroyed the receiver won't get broadcasts (even if the app is running, e.g. with another activity). Even if you use the application context, once the app is destroyed, that's cleared.

[From the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts):

> **Manifest-declared receivers**
>
> If you declare a broadcast receiver in your manifest, **the system launches your app** (if the app is not already running) when the broadcast is sent.

> **Context-registered receivers**
>
> Context-registered receivers receive broadcasts as long as their registering context is valid. For an example, if you register within an Activity context, you receive broadcasts as long as the activity is not destroyed. If you register with the Application context, you receive broadcasts **as long as the app is running**.

If you need your app to launch in the background (which you do if you're relying on alarms, which implies your app isn't in the foreground and could be destroyed when the alarm runs) you need to register the receiver in your manifest, so the system knows it's something your app handles

Comment: I see. I know how to do that for a receiver that is its own activity, but is it possible to declare in the manifest a receiver that is part of the MainActivity? If it is what do I choose for the name? (<receiver android:name="AlarmReceiver">)

Comment: A ``BroadcastReceiver`` is a class - you can't make an ``Activity`` into one, if that's what you mean. Also, as far as I know, you can't start an activity from an alarm (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts) - i.e. you can't just make an app pop up out of nowhere with no user action, outside of a few specific cases. Your example with messaging apps sounds like system notifications - you can do that, just create a notification in your receiver (or call the code that does that). It depends what your app needs to do in the background really

Comment: I see. Please add one sentence that clearly states it is not possible to do what I want using a context registered receiver to do what I want and I'll accept your answer, if you don't mind.